# Getting error while using gtk2hs-buildtool library in Haskell project using Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to add dependency of `gtk2hs-buildtool` to my Haskell project but following error while building stack.

```
In the dependencies for TicTacToe-0.1.0.0:
    gtk2hs-buildtools needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
                      version is 0.13.5.4)
needed since TicTacToe is a build target.
```

TicTacToe.cabal file:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      TicTacToeEngine
  other-modules:
      Paths_TicTacToe
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5,
      gtk2hs-buildtools
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

Comment: What if you add `gtk2hs-buildtools >=0.13.5.4 && <0.14` for example?

Comment: I think you need to specify some version constraint, similarly to the `base` line. E.g. `gtk2hs-buildtools >= 0.13 && < 0.14`.

Comment: Got this ```In the dependencies for TicTacToe-0.1.0.0:
    gtk2hs-buildtools must match >=0.13.5.4 && <0.14, but the stack configuration has no specified
                      version  (latest matching version is 0.13.5.4)```  @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `stack` tool you shouldn't touch the `<packagename>.cabal` file. `stack` is in charge to generate it from `package.yaml`. Despite of the fact that is a common practise to modify the `<packagename>.cabal`, development workflow will be easier if you don't.

The files you are interested in (and the ones that `stack` tool uses) are the `stack.yaml` and `package.yaml`.

In `stack.yaml` you should see an entry called `resolver: lts-XX.XX`. That means that your dependencies version are managed such that they match those in the given `lts` (a.k.a. `snapshot`). You can go to https://www.stackage.org/, click on your `lts` version and search for the `gtk2hs-buildtools` package to get the right version for your project (example: `lts-12.26` uses `gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.4.0`). In your `package.yaml`, in the `dependencies` section write the entry entry `- gtk2hs-buildtools`

From `lts-13.11` and above `gtk2hs-buildtools` is not available in stackage, so you need to add it as an extra-dep. in the `stack.yaml`, in the section `extra-dep` add the following entry `gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.4.0` (or the version number you'd like to use). Then add in the `package.yaml` and entry `gtk2hs-buildtools`. It is necessary to add the entry in both files. Refer to stack docs o understand why.

Just to ensure you can build your project, your files should something look like the following:

**if using resolver above or equal to `13.11`**

`stack.yaml`

```
resolver: lts-13.11
extra-deps: 
 - gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.4.0
```

`package.yaml`

```
dependencies:
 - base
 - gtk2hs-buildtools
```

**if using resolver below `13.11`**

`stack.yaml`

```
resolver: lts-12.26
extra-deps:
```

`package.yaml`

```
dependencies:
 - base
 - gtk2hs-buildtools
```